# how to create an interface that will fetch info from API?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch-api

I wanted to create an interface that will fetch brewery information, based on a brewery/beer name. I fetch the API to my code but I don't know how to get the info from it with my button. I want it to show me at least two locations but get an error every time. I'm new to JS and so confused here,
The error is: 404 page not found- when submitting the city name. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>The Beer Mapping</h1>

  <script>
    fetch("http://beermapping.com/webservice/locquery/API_KEY")
    .then(response=>{
      return response.json()
    }).then(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    }).then(error=>{
      console.log(error)
    }));
  </script>

  <form action="/action_page.php">
   <input type="text" name="City Name">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There was a syntax error that I assume was a typo. Your `fetch()` did not have a closing parenthesis `)` so I added it in and made indentation more consistent. Could you [edit] your question and possibly provide what the error was along with its stack trace?

Comment: So I put the API key but it doesnt work, it say it's 404 error, page not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the examples page of the API at https://beermapping.com/api/examples/, it appears that the API endpoint you are attempting to use requires a parameter to be provided after the API key:
http://beermapping.com/webservice/locquery/API_KEY/QUERY
If you are to load that page in your browser, you will get a blank page (presumably as no valid API key provided) rather than a 404 error, so I assume once you provide your API key this should eliminate the 404 error being received.

Looking at the rest of your code I assume that the parameter needed is based off the user input from the City Name field - so this is most likely the parameter that needs passing into the query URL after the API key.

Based on the form submission URL being a PHP file, one way to pass the user input would be to use  after the API Key in the URL:

```
fetch("http://beermapping.com/webservice/locquery/API_KEY/<?php echo $_GET['City Name']; ?>")
```

however it would also be possible to process this entirely client side by changing your form handling to instead fetch the URL rather than calling an endpoint on your web server.

Comment: I put the api key but still is 404. how can I connect the submit button to the api ?

Comment: As per my response above, it seems you need to provide a query after the API key also - could you clarify whether you have tried this? Your comment seems to suggest you have only tried with an API key, and not a query parameter. My response above also covers one way of connecting the submit button to the API - again, could you clarify if you have attempted the suggestions above, and if you have and this hasn't worked, provided some details of the errors occurring.

Comment: I did. I dont know how to do a query with ajax (which I am required to use). I used fetch with the api key/city but it doesnt take me to the api. I'm confused what am I doing wrong here? // now I am using input id instead of form

Comment: So I have no errors now in th ecode, how can I call it with submit button?

Comment: You could either:
- Make the form destination of the user input the same file as the calling file (so form action=""), and pass the user parameter in server side through PHP (as I mentioned above)
- Use JavaScript & an event on the button click to call a function which executes the code to fetch the data from the API (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)